# Tensorflow 2 does not have a a fully_connected function How can I simulate that?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am making a CNN model to use for lane detection. But tensorflow 2 does not have tf.contrib therefore i cannot access the fully_connected layer.

How can I make my own Fully connected layer function?

This is my model so far:

```py
conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d
batch_norm = tf.nn.batch_normalization
dropout = tf.nn.dropout
max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool2d
softmax = tf.nn.softmax
relu = tf.nn.relu
avg_pool = tf.nn.avg_pool2d
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint







def network(x):
    model = conv2d(x,filters=[1,5,5,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
    model = relu(model)
    model = batch_norm(model)
    model = max_pool(model)

    model = conv2d(model,filters=[1,4,4,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
    model = relu(model)
    model = batch_norm(model)
    model = max_pool(model)

    model = conv2d(model,filters=[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
    model = relu(model)
    model = batch_norm(model)
    model = avg_pool(model)

    model = dropout(model,0.3)
    # i want to add the fully connect layer here then a softmax layer then another fully connected
```

Comment: the `tf.keras` api is the [preferred way](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2#use_keras_layers_and_models_to_manage_variables) to build models in tensorflow 2

Comment: I highly recommend using `tf.keras`, your use case fits neatly into `tf.keras.Sequential`, but if you prefer a [functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional), it's also available.

Comment: Ok. Thank you  for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is the Dense layer in the keras module - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense